# Loop function for comparing the columns

Tags: r

I have a very large data set including 400 string and numeric variables. I want to compare each two consequiative columns 3&4, 5&6, etc.  I am going to compare the third variable (.x) with fourth (.y) , fifth with sixth one, seventh one with eightth one and so on in the following way:  if (.y) is NA then we replace the NA with the value of corresponding row from (.x) . For example if  number .y is NA we replace NA with the corresponding value from number .x which would be 5. Again, if day.y  is NA we  replace NA in day.y with the corresponding value from day.x  which would be  3. How can I write a loope function to do that?

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA,NA,5,5,6)
B<-c(3,4,5,6,1,2,7,6,7,NA,NA,6)
number.x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA,NA,5,5,6)
number.y<-c(3,4,5,6,1,2,7,6,7,NA,NA,6)
day.x<-c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,NA,3,5,3)
day.y<-c(4,5,6,7,8,7,8,1,2,3,5,NA)
school.x<-c("a","b","b","c","n","f","h","NA","F","G","z","h")
school.y<-c("a","b","b","c","m","g","h","NA","NA","G","H","T")
city.x<- c(1,2,3,7,5,8,7,5,6,7,5,1)
city.y<- c(1,2,3,5,5,7,7,NA,NA,3,4,5)
df<-data.frame(A,B,number.x,number.y,day.x,day.y,school.x,school.y,city.x,city.y)
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hacked approach to your question and it requires that every two columns are going to be compared against one another.

```
library(dplyr)

start_group <- seq(1, length(df), by = 2)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(df))
for(i in start_group){

  i <- i
  j <- i + 1

  dnames <- df[, c(i, j)] %>%
    names

  df_ <- data.frame(col1 = df[, i],
                    col2 = df[, j]) %>%
    mutate(col1 = ifelse(is.na(col1), col2 %>% paste, col1 %>% paste)) %>%
    mutate(col2 = ifelse(is.na(col2), col1 %>% paste, col2 %>% paste))

  names(df_) <- dnames

  df2 <- cbind(df2, df_)

}
df2[, -1]

   number.x number.y day.x day.y school.x school.y city.x city.y
1         1        3     1     4        a        a      1      1
2         2        4     3     5        b        b      2      2
3         3        5     4     6        b        b      3      3
4         4        6     5     7        c        c      7      5
5         5        1     6     8        n        m      5      5
6         6        2     7     7        f        g      8      7
7         7        7     8     8        h        h      7      7
8         6        6     1     1       NA       NA      5      5
9         7        7     2     2        F        F      6      6
10        5        5     3     3        G        G      7      3
11        5        5     5     5        z        H      5      4
12        6        6     3     3        h        T      1      5
```

Comment: I like pipes to avoid nesting several layers deep, but do you really find `col2 %>% paste` more readable than `paste(col2)`?

Comment: @shadi surely you can adjust the code yourself (delete the `mutate(col1 = ...)`) do exactly what you want... this gets you almost there which is quite fortunate since you didn't explicitly show desired output.

Comment: @Gregor, i really dont have to use pipes.  :)  it's actually a bad(?) habit i picked up recently as its clearly more keystrokes than typing `paste(col2)`.    i do like how clean it looks tho with the pipes.

Comment: I mean, it's all style so there's not an explicit right or wrong, but one of the chief goals should be readability and transparency. *I* think that pipes are great when they make commands that would be multiply nested and necessary to read from inside out into something nicely readable left to right, but I generally find piping for a single command (no nesting) and pipes *within* another command (especially one that is also piped) harder to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following base R solution. Essentially, it loops through a distinct list of column stem names (number, day, school, class) and replaces NA values in `.x` columns with corresponding `NA` values in `.y` columns and vice versa. NOTE: Schools column require conversion from factor to character and one of its rows has `NA` in both `.x` and `.y` columns

```
# CONVERT TO CHARACTER (NOTE: NA VALUE BECOME "NA" STRINGS)
df[,c('school.x', 'school.y')] <- 
  sapply(df[,c('school.x', 'school.y')], as.character)

# SET UP FINAL DF
finaldf <- df

# OBTAIN UNIQUE LIST OF COLUMNS STEM (W/O x AND y SUFFIXES)
distinctcols <- unique(gsub("[.][x]|[.][y]", "", names(df)[49:ncol(df)]))

# LOOP THROUGH COLUMN STEM REPLACING NA VALUES
for (col in distinctcols) {
  # REPLACE NA .x COLUMN VALUES
  finaldf[is.na(finaldf[paste0(col,'.x')])|finaldf[paste0(col,'.x')]=="NA",
     paste0(col,'.x')] <- 
  finaldf[is.na(finaldf[paste0(col,'.x')])|finaldf[paste0(col,'.x')]=="NA",
     paste0(col,'.y')]

  # REPLACE NA .y COLUMN VALUES       
  finaldf[is.na(finaldf[paste0(col,'.y')])|finaldf[paste0(col,'.y')]=="NA", 
     paste0(col,'.y')] <- 
  finaldf[is.na(finaldf[paste0(col,'.y')])|finaldf[paste0(col,'.y')]=="NA",
     paste0(col,'.x')]    
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    number.x    number.y    day.x   day.y   school.x    school.y    city.x  city.y
1          1           3        1       4          a           a         1       1
2          2           4        3       5          b           b         2       2
3          3           5        4       6          b           b         3       3
4          4           6        5       7          c           c         7       5
5          5           1        6       8          n           m         5       5
6          6           2        7       7          f           g         8       7
7          7           7        8       8          h           h         7       7
8          6           6        1       1         NA          NA         5       5
9          7           7        2       2          F           F         6       6
10         5           5        3       3          G           G         7       3
11         5           5        5       5          z           H         5       4
12         6           6        3       3          h           T         1       5
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your great advice. I have a question. In my original data set which include 400 col the first 50 variables do not include any .x or .y and from 51th variable the comparison of replacing .y with .x will start. Would you please tell how to modify the above code to my situation.

Comment: Easy change. Simply add a a bracketed column range beside `names()` in the `distinctcols` list definition. Since column names list is zero-based, I made the range 49 to number of df's columns. See edit. By the way, this is not even needed. R will not error out or touch any column that does not have the `.x` or `.y` suffix.

Comment: It sure does work with character types. See output. The `NA` value for `school.y` did change to `F`. On another row though your post had NAs for both. Did you read the NOTE in my answer? Also strings must be converted from factor to character first which I include at beginning.

Comment: @ Parfait,Thanks for your reply, but when I run the code, it does not replace NA from school.y with F from school.x. I just Edited the value of school.y from F to NA after you kindly provided the code.Also,the problem that I have in my data set is, I have 400 variables all in factor format although half of them are numeric. I do not want to convert them to characters by mentioning their names since there are too many variables.How I convert them without mentioning their names?

Comment: Also by using unique function the final output doenot include all variables (the ones without any .x and .y). How can I have a full data set including all variables (.x,.y and the rest of the variables)